# I need help computing the effect of curvature on the FRW metric

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, curvature, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Apparently there are different forms of the FLRW metric.  I'm focusing on Anti-de Sitter space, so I'll just give the hyperbolic version of the function.
$$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a^2(t)\left[dr^2+R_0\space \sinh\left(\frac{r}{R_0}\right)d\Omega^2\right]\tag 1$$
$$d\Omega^2=d\theta^2+sin^2 \theta\space d\phi^2$$
Here, $d\Omega$ is the angular separation of two points in the sky, but I'm not interested in two points in the sky.  I'm analyzing SNe Ia data, so I'm just working in line-of-sight measurements, so as I understand this, the $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ terms go to zero (that is, there's no change in the angle), so the whole $d\Omega$ term is zero.  This leaves us with:
$$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a^2(t)dr^2$$
Which doesn't seem right.  Is the distance in a hyperbolic plane the same as a flat plane or closed surface if you're not dealing with angular separation?  Am I interpreting the metric correctly?

**EDIT:** The other form of the FRW metric seems to suggest the curvature changes the length of a line-of-sight measurement.
$$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a^2(t)\left[\frac{dr^2}{1+k\space r^2}+r^2d\Omega^2\right]\tag 2$$
Where $k$ is either a scalar (1 for closed, 0 for flat, -1 for saddle) or the Gaussian Curvature (still not sure how that's used).  Setting the angular separation to zero, you get:
$$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a^2(t)\frac{dr^2}{1+k\space r^2}$$
This seems to fly in the face of the version in (1), so I'm missing some major concept here.  Can anyone tell me what that is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct equation should be

$$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2+a^2(t)[\frac{dr^2}{1-\kappa r^2} + r^2d\Omega^2]$$

Here $r$ is the usual radial coordinate.

We may re-define the radial coordinate by taking $$d\chi = \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-\kappa r^2}}$$ such that

$$r =
\begin{cases}
sinh(\chi), & \kappa = -1 \\
\chi & \kappa = 0 \\
sin(\chi) & \kappa = 1
\end{cases}$$

This implies
$$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + a^2(t)[d\chi^2 + S_{\kappa}^2(\chi)d\Omega^2]$$

where

$$S_{\kappa}(\chi) =
\begin{cases}
sinh(\chi), & \kappa = -1 \\
\chi & \kappa = 0 \\
sin(\chi) & \kappa = 1
\end{cases}$$

So in both cases when $d\Omega = 0$, we have the same result.

Comment: Please have a look at the Wiki page for the FLRW metric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric.  The section labeled **Hyperspherical coordinates** doesn't appear to agree with your second definition.  Is the Wiki page wrong (I'm perfectly happy to accept that, I'm just looking for clarity here)?

Comment: W/r/t my original question: how does $\kappa$ capture the positive or negative curvature?  It's just an integer.  For example, for $\kappa = 1$, your equation has the same metric for that of a 3-sphere where the curvature is equal to the radius.  How does this metric deal with, for example, an open universe where $\kappa \ne -\frac{1}{r^2}$

Comment: It says "In hyperspherical or curvature-normalized coordinates the coordinate r". So it actually uses another coordinate system but writes the coordinate as $r$ which is confusing

Comment: @GluonSoup You can look at http://theory.uchicago.edu/~liantaow/my-teaching/dark-matter-472/lectures.pdf  page 9, section 1.1.2

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't address my original question: how does an integer (-1, 0, +1) give us anything other than a perfectly round curvature (or flat plane for 0)?  Said differently, if you select +1 for $\kappa$, the formula reflects a perfect sphere ($\kappa=\frac{1}{r^2}$).  How does this metric allow for, say, a hyperbolic plane with an arbitrary curvature?

Comment: @GluonSoup  I think your original question was about why $d\Omega = 0$ does not give the same answer for both metrics ? I do not see a statement about the meaning of the curvature in your original question.  Did you looked at the pdf that I shared ? Different $\kappa$ represents different "shapes" more formally different metric. When you have a positive curvature you ll have a sphere, if the curvature is zero it means you are on flat space if the curvature is negative you are on the hyperbolic space.

Comment: @GluonSoup Metric does not determine the curvature. Curvature determines the metric.

Comment: The metric defines a perfect sphere for positive curvature.  A perfect sphere is just one of an infinite number of possible geometries having positive curvature.  The same can be said of the negative curvature: the $k$ constant has a single value of $k=-1$, and so the FLRW metric (as stated here) has only one of an infinite number of possible negative curvatures.  I would like to understand if I'm interpreting the FLRW metric correctly and, if so, why does 'positive curvature' imply a perfect sphere?  Are other hyper-spheroids not allowed?

Comment: Also, I read the paper you linked and it just confused me more as they mentioned that $k$ scales with $a(t)$.  How can $k$ scale if it takes on one of three values?

Comment: @GluonSoup I see your point. It does not allow another geometries due to cosmological principle. Such that the universe should be homogeneous and isotropic. Perfect sphere is the only geometry which has a constant positive curvature and have this property.

Comment: @GluonSoup "$k$  scales with $a(t)$". What is the page number ?

Comment: `What is the page number ?`  Same page you referenced, 9.  `This means that the geometry of the spacetime stays the same if we simultaneously rescale
a, r and k as in (1.1.20)`  Again, how does $k$ scale if it takes on one of three values?

Comment: @GluonSoup It means that the important thing is not being $+1$ or $-1$ buthaving positive or negative curvature. We are scaling in such a way that positive curvature means $k=1$ negative curvature means $k=-1$. $k=+1$ just means that we have a positive curvature. You can have another positive $k$ values but you can always re-scale them to make it $k=+1$.

Comment: See, that's the thing I'm having trouble with.  I don't think it means that, I think it means if $k > 0$ then we have positive curvature, if $k=0$ then we have a flat plane, if $k<0$ then we have negative curvature, but $k$ doesn't appear to be an integer, it appears to be a real number with the possible interpretation of Gaussian Curvature (that is, it appears to me that $k=\frac{1}{r_{c1}*r_{c2}}$, but I can't find confirmation of this).

Comment: @GluonSoup The existence of $\kappa$ at all implies an isotropic, homogeneous universe. It is just that regardless of its value you can always rescale your coordinates in a way such that $\kappa$ becomes one of those values depending on its sign

Comment: @GluonSoup If we are assuming that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic, then we have only 3 possible values for $k$. For instance the torus does not have a $\kappa$ value beacause the space is not homogeneous and isotropic.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, there's a major concept that seems to be missing from all of the papers I read on this subject: **in closed and open geometries, the radius is not related to the circumference by $2 \pi$**.  This means that angles don't work the way you would expect them to.  Obviously standard trig operations wouldn't work.

To illustrate this, let's take a walk on this sphere from the north pole to point P.

[image]

Let's say **$\chi$** is $30^o$ and **a** is 1.  The distance from the pole to P is then $\frac{30}{360}\times 1\times 2\pi=\frac{1}{6}\pi$.  The circumference of a circle with this radius is, $\frac{1}{6}\pi \times 2\pi=\frac{1}{3}\pi^2$. However, the actual circumference at latitude P is $Sin(30)\times 1\times 2\pi=\pi$.  We see that $\frac{1}{3}\pi^2\gt\pi$.

So in order to get the angles to work like they do in Euclidean space, the actual distance travelled in space is reduced so that it's $2\pi$ of the circumference.
So the big missing concept here is that the radial coordinate is not the distance in
$$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a^2(t)\left[\frac{dr^2}{1+k\space r^2}+r^2d\Omega^2\right]$$

but it is the actual comoving distance in this version of the metric:

$$ds^2=-c^2dt^2+a^2(t)\left[dr^2 + S_k^2(r)d\Omega^2\right]$$

This doesn't negate, in any way, the answer by Reign, it's just intended to give a more intuitive explanation of why the two formulas are different.  This is the difference between **Reduced-Circumference Polar Coordinates** and **Hyperspherical Coordinates**.

Comment: I find an article if you are interested. http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~serguei/teaching/cosmology.pdf It seems nice